# What symbol/figure should I use to demonstrate a game ended in a draw in a table?

Tags: layout, tables

In my program, a user will write a bot and at the end of the benchmark it will be showed to them a table showing how the bot did against some premade bots in some maps.

What I have now is this:

[image]

(The width of the columns are different because there were the bots name there, I changed to P1, P2, etc to make it more clear)

Even though I am satisfied with the green check mark and the red X, I'm not entirely confident about using an equal sign to demonstrate a game ended in a draw.

Is this the best approach? Personally I prefer to show "signs" than to write "Win/Loss/Draw" but I would like to hear some opinions.

I'm open to suggestions about the check mark and "X" too.

Comment: How much time have you spent on pinterest examining the score boards of games and apps?

Comment: Why not to use **W**, **L**, **D** colored letters? You can place it in the round filled shapes to make it look more consistent on their width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:
[image]

- Shapes are consistent in width
- Icons are easy to recognize, due to W, L, D letters. Though, a legend or tooltip is good to provide, too

Comment: That looks great!

Comment: Obviously this will depend on overall colour schemes etc., but _personally_, I'd probably go for a non-grey colour for the draws (perhaps a not too-dark shade of blue?). To me, the grey is too suggestive of disabled controls, but _might_ work if you either needed to indicate a match _couldn't_ be played for some reason (perhaps with an `X`) or possibly (if this can happen) if a match has not yet been played (perhaps with an `-`).